# How to tell search engines like Google to display its tabs/url?

Tags: web, seo, web-deployment

When we search in google engine it displays top web site tabs or links too. Like when we search "bing" or "net beans".

Q: How it displays those links. Do we have to tell it to display these links.

Q: Does it something have to do with sitemap.xml/robots.txt or it displays the links present in index.php of that website?

> Robots.txt: allow/disallow bots to crawl which page.
>
> sitemap.xml: tells the map/loc of your website pages and also tells the frequency.

Q: How does it display description of a website?

I have searched about description it has to do with meta tag name description. But i open the source file of [net beans](https://netbeans.org/)

```
<META NAME="description" CONTENT="Welcome to NetBeans">
```

But the description google showing is

```
Fully-featured Java IDE written completely in Java, with many modules available, such as: debugger, form editor, object browser, CVS, emacs integration, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

For your first question I should say that those links which you've mentioned are automatically genereted in top most visited websites and portals. If you'd set the `sitemap.xml` and `robots.txt` correctly in your website root folder, After a while if your website has a lot of visitors traffic, google detect your top most visited links which users most redirect to and show them in its result as you wish.

For the second question meta tags are not the only criteria the search engines show them in their results, Rather they catch the page content and extract the context from the text content of the page and show the description based on your entered keyword. However your meta description will be shown when keyword is the website name or its domain.

Take a look at [Open Graph Protocol](http://ogp.me/) to extend your information about meta tags and your requirements for seo.

Regards